# Using Canvas in Windows Form .net application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, canvas

I want to create a `Winform` application which displays `Datagrid`, `Charts` on it. My requirement is, that the user should be able to position those elements according to his choice, like we drop `text box`, `label` in winform design view. I know that there is a `Canvas` class in WPF, but I want to achieve the same with `Winforms`.

Can I use the WPF `Canvas` in `Winform`? Or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a WPF Canvas in a Windows Forms application.  Just place the Canvas inside of an [ElementHost control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx).

Comment: Hey Reed, Thanks for such a quick reply :). Could you point out some example like I mentioned in my requirements, It will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this code while searching for an answer, it comes from a Stephens' VB trainer example:

```
Dim canvas As New Bitmap(
        picCanvas.ClientSize.Width,
        picCanvas.ClientSize.Height)
```