# VB6 -> VB.NET ... Cannot find the Canvas control in .NET

Tags: vb.net, vb6, wpf-controls

I am trying to convert some old VB6 code to VB.NET. The VB6 uses a Canvas control, simply

```
Dim cv as Canvas
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to use the Canvas control in VB.NET (using VS2005). MSDN says it is in the System.Windows.Controls namespace, which doesn't seem to exist? All I see is System.Windows.Forms, which doesn't include the Canvas control. Any tips?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Canvas in Windows Form .net application.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716379/using-canvas-in-windows-form-net-application)

Comment: In your VB6 project press F2 and do a search for canvas - that might give you a clue as to what this control is. If your VB6 project compiles then you must have a reference to this somewhere - right click on you toolbox and review the controls or look at Project>Refrerences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find out what the Canvas was in VB6, then you will be able to see what the nearest equivalent is in VB.Net.

I think it must have been an obscure third-party control or possibly some custom code. I've not come across Canvas before in VB6

Answer (score 0):

In recent history things have changed a bit here. There are now two sets of windows frameworks.

Forms are the old one. The new ones are controls, and they come in the WPF and Silverlight variety. WPF is to replace windows forms, silverlight is meant for the web, etc etc.

Since you are using the older VS2005, I believe you will need to install the WPF extensions to get access to them.

**Unfortunately** the WPF Extensions for VS2005 are no longer supported by Microsoft:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/acangialosi/archive/2008/06/27/vs-2005-extensions-for-net-framework-3-0-wpf-wcf-ctp-is-coming-off-the-ms-download-center.aspx

You can still get them from various places, but for your own ease you should probably consider upgrading to at least VS2008 if you want to use WPF/Silverlight.

Comment: So Canvas works in VB6, not in VS2005, but it works again in VS2008?

Comment: I'm afraid I've never used VB6 so I'm not sure what was available back then or how it relates. The XAML-based Canvas for WPF/Silverlight is new-ish and I don't know enough about their predecessors to say.

Comment: -1 Probably best not to try and answer questions tagged VB6 if you have never used it.

Comment: Are you serious? It was also tagged .NET and wpf-controls, and I directly answered the question of why the Canvas control does not work in 2005. Do you think that the answer I provided does not answer the original question?